# doubts about C pointers while studying

Tags: c, pointers

While studying C language for university I ran into some uncertainties about pointers, so I wrote the most simple code I could think about it.

```
void test1(int *int_pointer) {
    *int_pointer = 5; 
}

void test2(int *int_pointer) {
    int i = 6;
    int_pointer = &i; 
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 8;
    int *p = &n;
    test1(p);
    test2(p);
}
```

Why if I `printf("%i", * int_pointer)` into test2 function it prints out 6 while `printf("%i", * p)` in main comes out 5 (and not 6)?

The second question is about the following code.

```
int main (void) {
int var1 = 10;
int * var1p = & var1;
int var2 = * var1p / 2;
int * var2p = &var2;
var1 = 40;
printf("%i", * var2p);
}
```

Why in this case comes out 5 and not 20 if I change var1 value and var2p points to var2 (which is equals to * var1p / 2)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To better understand pointers  it helped taking a pencil drawing pictures with little boxes presenting memory and arrows pointing around between them.

Comment: In `test2` the function receives a *copy of* the pointer where the address of a local variable is assigned to the copy. So on return from In `test2` no changes in `test2` are ever seen back in `main()`. In the next case, `var2` is set before `var1` is reset to `40`, so the only values used by `var2` are from when `var1 = 10`.

Comment: A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found in memory. Keep clear in your mind whether you are changing the address held by the pointer (e.g. `int_pointer = &i;`) or whether you are changing the value in memory at the address held by the pointer (e.g. `*int_pointer = 5;`) Note the pure assignment to the pointer in the first case, and assignment to the dereferenced pointer used in the second to update the value stored at the pointed to memory address..

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

- You initialize a variable `n` and you make a `p` pointer to point at
  it.
- Then you give the value of the `p` (the address of `n`) to `test1()`
  and change the value of the memory field that is pointed by
  `int_pointer` (and `int_pointer` has the same value as `p`, so it
  changes the value of `n`.
- When you call `test2()` and give you the same address, but in the
  function you change the value of the local `int_pointer`, so it will
  point to the local `i`, but the `p` stays the same.

So that is why in the `test2()` function 6 is printed (the value that
   is pointed by `int_pointer`), and in the `main()` 5 is printed (the
   value that is pointed by `p`).

The second case:

- You initialize `var1` to 10, and then you make `var1p` to point at
  it.
- Then you initialize `var2` to half, what is pointed by `var1p`, so
  10/2=5.
- Then you initialize `var2p`, so it will point to `var2`.
- After that, you change the value of `var1` but `var2` stays the same,
  so that is why you getting 5.

`var1` and `var2` is two different variable, so they have their own
   fields in memory. If you want 40 to be printed you should make
   `var2p` to point at `var1`, like `var2p = &var1`.

Answer (score 1):

`test1` modifies the variable pointed by `int_pointer` (`main`'s `n`).

`test2` modifies the pointer itself. Argument variables are local to the function to which they belong, and changing them has no effect on the caller.

For example, the following has no effect on the caller either:

```
void test3(int i) {
    i = 9;
}

test(n);
```

If you wanted to modify a pointer in the caller, you'd have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void test4(int **int_pointer_pointer) {
    int *int_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *int_pointer = 10;
    *int_pointer_pointer = int_pointer;
}

int *int_pointer;
test4(&int_pointer);
printf("%d\n", *int_pointer);
free(int_pointer);
```

Note that returning (normally or via arguments) a pointer to a local variable makes no sense because it ceases to exists when the function returns. That's why I used `malloc`+`free` instead of a local variable.